# Tridion 2011 SP1 Content Delivery dynamic linking dll version compatibility error

Tags: 2011-sp1, upgrade

We have a setup of SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1 Content Manager and Content Delivery on separate Windows Server 2008 R2.
We have have upgraded Content delivery server from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012 R2.

Now after upgrade we are facing following error:

`Tridion Content Delivery Deployment Errors: “Unable to load DLL ‘xmogrt`

and

`System.BadImageFormatException`

I have checked few resources suggestions available on Stackechange which suggested  version compatibility issues with JVM as root cause.
I tried the suggested options but issue is not resolved.

Further I am not too sure that SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1 Content Delivery will be supported on Windows Server 2012 R2.
Any guidance / suggestion will be really helpful.

Regards

Comment: Although it's not an officially supported windows version, this error indicates a mismatch between the JVM 'bitness' and IIS bitness. Play with 'Allow 32-bits something' in the Application Pool settings from your website in IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi jaindhiraj and welcome to Tridion Stackexchange. The answer is simple enough but probably not the one you were hoping for. Windows Server 2012 is **not supported**, see [HERE](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-A1E08316-798A-41E8-8054-301002C69C2E&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-5720A693-1F0A-432E-80B5-F9A07C1FDD1B.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-A1E08316-798A-41E8-8054-301002C69C2E).

Since everything was working on Server 2008, the solution would be to revert to the old version of the OS if you intend on using that version of Tridion, which by the way is waaaaay outdated. Having that in mind, the best course of action would be instead to upgrade Tridion altogether to get support for newer OS-s and database servers, and to be able to use some powerful new features introduced in the later versions of Tridion.